# Telerik MVC grid loses rendered html on sort

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a telerik grid in my ASP MVC project. Most of the columns are bound to data from DB, but one columns needs to contain image icons that are dependent on a column record's value. To do this I use a column template that contains an IF ELSE. The IF ELSE writes html with a specific image reference (css class with background image) depending on a column record's value.  This work great on load.  But as soon as I perform a sort on the grid, all that html that was rendered in the templated column is lost.  Code below. Is there a way to do this or do I have to rethink how I do a sort?

```
<div id="gridArea" >

    @{Html.Telerik().Grid(@Model)
        .Name("Grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
             { columns.Template(
                 @<text>
                     @if (@item.Q1 == "On Plan")
                     {<div class="scorecardSymbol onPlanSymbol"></div>}
                     else if (@item.Q1 == "Off Plan")
                     {<div class="scorecardSymbol offPlanSymbol"></div>}
                     else if (@item.Q1 == "Serious Constraints")
                     {<div class="scorecardSymbol seriousConstraintsSymbol"></div>}
                     else if (@item.Q1 == "Not Started")
                     {<div class="scorecardSymbol notStartedSymbol"></div>}
                     else
                     {<span>NA</span> }
                 </text>)

                .HeaderTemplate(
                     @<text> 
                        <span style="color:red">Quarter Status</span>
                     </text>)
                .Width(175);
             columns.Bound("Off_Plan").Width(100).Title("Off Plan");
           })
       .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
         {
            dataBinding.Server().Select("Index", "Home", new { ajax = true });
            dataBinding.Ajax().Select("_FirstLook", "Home").Enabled(true);
          })
       .Render();
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Server-side templates do not work in ajax binding mode. You need to use a client-side template in this case. You could find more info in this help topic: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-troubleshooting.html#ClientTemplates